# How to use Bitbucket as a maven remote repository?

Tags: git, maven, bitbucket

We are planning to use bitbucket as source code repository as well remote repository for our maven based projects. I have created a repository on bitbucket something like below:

https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/maven-repository

How can I push my company specific project jars into the above remote repository using the project specific pom.xml? Can you help me with a sample pom.xml? We would be pushing all company specific jars into the above remote repository to be used by other projects within the company as maven dependencies.

Here is what I was trying so far to push one sample project into the remote repo:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>corporate-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>MyCompanyRepo</id>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/maven-repository</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The above is a parent pom, which will be included by all the other projects within the company and I wanted to push this to the remote repo to be used by other company specific projects.

When  I run **mvn deploy** command, this is the error I get:

```
C:\Cooler\Work\dev\Projects\mycompany\wal-common>mvn deploy
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'snapshotPolicy' (position: START_TAG seen ...</layo
ut>\n          <snapshotPolicy>... @203:27)  @ C:\Users\cooler\.m2\settings.xml,
line 203, column 27
[WARNING]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building corporate-pom 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ corporate-pom
---
[INFO] Installing C:\Cooler\Work\dev\Projects\mycompany\wal-common\pom.xml to C:\
Users\cooler\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\corporate-pom\1.0\corporat
e-pom-1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ corporate-pom ---
Uploading: https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/maven-repository/com/mycompany/corporate-   pom/1.0/corporate-pom-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.607s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 17 14:33:01 MST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:
deploy (default-deploy) on project corporate-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Co
uld not transfer artifact com.mycompany:corporate-pom:pom:1.0 from/
to CompanyREPO (https://bitbucket.org/mycompany/maven-repository): Connection to h
ttp://:8080 refused: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15):

You can try http://synergian.github.io/wagon-git/index.html it has instructions for bitbucket.

An alternative to using bitbucket is to use a dropbox folder for company.  https://code.google.com/p/peter-lavalle/wiki/MavenOnDropBox  Contains a very good step by step guide on how to do this.

Comment: +1 for synergian, very easy setup; I can't imagine a quicker way to setup a maven repository if you already use git.

Answer (score 11):

Install jars in a local maven repository.

Make a directory e.g. maven-repo/repository

cd into maven-repo

execute the following (replacing the arguments by the ones that are relevant to your jar):

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.rapid_i -DartifactId=rapidminer -Dversion=5.3.006 -Dfile=/path/to/artifact/rapidminer.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DlocalRepositoryPath=./repository  -DcreateChecksum=true
```

Share the folder to a BitBucket public repository.

Create a repository in your pom.xml pointing to you bitbucket folder.(you must use /raw/master in the path https://bitbucket.org/your-user-or-group/your_maven-repo**/raw/master/** !!)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.activeintel</groupId>
<artifactId>rapidminer-proj</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version> 

<!-- Dependency to jar on Maven Repository on Git-BitBucket -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rapid_i</groupId>
        <artifactId>rapidminer</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.006</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!-- Maven Repository on Git-BitBucket -->
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>neil_rubens-repository</id>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/your-user-or-group/your_maven-repo/raw/master/repository/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

</project>
```

Source: [**Hosting Maven Repository for third-party jars on Git** (Bitbucket/Github)](http://activeintelligence.org/blog/archive/hosting-maven-repository-for-third-party-jars-on-git-bitbucketgithub/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: i think this might be the best of the best, also madam @kleopatra  i think the top answer above needs your attention with that comment.. :)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I push my company specific project jars into the above remote
>   repository using the project specific pom.xml?

You <strike>can't.</strike> shouldn't in my opinion.

[Bitbucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket) is not intended to be a [maven repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). Trying to get maven to deploy artifacts to BitBucket <strike>to it is just wrong</strike> *may* contravene Atlassian's terms of use. On the other hand it might be fine.

You <strike>either need to</strike>  should instead deploy to your own local repository or a public one.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. People clearly have done this [(like this guy)](http://blog.chrissom.com/dev/bitbucket-as-a-maven-repository.html) and as ams says, wagon-git aims to do just this.

Comment: Thanks @BigMikeW, I was not aware of wrapper plugins like wagon-git doing this - an interesting concept. I'll update my answer in light of this. I do wonder though how Atlassian would classify this kind of use under its terms of use policy - specifically [section 3.5](https://www.atlassian.com/end-user-agreement?utm_source=bitbucket&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=footer). I wouldn't do it, but hey if it works, it works.

Comment: they seem to be meaning no multimedia file hosting in that section. I know there are instructions on how to host static web sites from Bitbucket and also if you look at [this defect](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7101/bug-accessing-private-reposotory-with) they don't take issue with it in the comments.

Comment: wagon-git is a general purpose git wagon, not just for Bitbucket or Github. Anyway, I'm adding some disclaimer notes. Thanks.

Comment: @mounds Do you think I can reference a [Maven repository hosted in Stash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38747160/how-to-use-stash-as-a-maven-remote-repository-for-a-gradle-project) from Gradle?

Comment: I don't see why not - as @mschonaker says above, git wagon is a general purpose solution so it should work with any git repo.

Answer (score 1):

I've now managed to get this working. I followed [these instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20131014101143/http://blog.chrissom.com/dev/bitbucket-as-a-maven-repository.html) and I can deploy artifacts to bitbucket and then use those in another maven project.

The tweaks I had to make to get it working were:

1. Upgrade Wagon-Git to v0.2.0
2. Configure Git using git config --global user.email as it didn't seem to be picking up the --local setting I had used previously

I also manually added a README.md to the repo but I don't think this was actually required.

Once you have successfully deployed to the repo you should see all your files in the usual way via the BitBucket web front end.

Comment: Your 'these instructions' link is dead! :(

Comment: You're right @Abby. Sorry I didn't make a copy of them!

Comment: I am trying to setup an internal repository with [Stash (now named Bitbucket Server)](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server). Did anyone do this successfully?