# Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect in maven.

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, xslt, testng

I have uploaded "reporty-ng" jars to resolve the [plugin](https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng) dependencies on my bit bucket account, but i get this Error when i run mvn clean . There is no setting has been done in "seetings.xml"

```
    C:\Users\Devraj\workspace\TestProject>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - TestProject:TestProject:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://bitbucket.org/Devraj/reporty-ng/reporty-ng/1.2/reporty-ng- 1.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'reporty-ng:reporty-ng:pom:1.2' from repository reporty-ng (https://bitbucket.org/Devraj): Error transferring file:        Co
nnection timed out: connect
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/reporty-ng/reporty-ng/1.2/reporty-ng-1.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'reporty-ng:reporty-ng:pom:1.2' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/reporty-ng/reporty-ng/1.2/reporty-ng-1.2.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'reporty-ng:reporty-ng:pom:1.2' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: reporty-ng:reporty-ng

Reason: POM 'reporty-ng:reporty-ng' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  reporty-ng:reporty-ng:pom:1.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  reporty-ng (https://bitbucket.org/Devraj)

 for project reporty-ng:reporty-ng


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 25 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 05 14:49:09 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/73M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The URL https://bitbucket.org/Devraj/reporty-ng/reporty-ng/1.2/reporty-ng-1.2.pom returns 404. Are you sure the URL is right?

Comment: Start using a repository manager or fix the connection timeout problem.

Comment: Take a look at this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18859138/546117

Comment: @blackbuild Yes! the URL is correct

Comment: @khmarbaise . Please elaborate about using "repository manager"

Comment: Take a deep look at this: https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't upload foreign artifacts to your bitbucket account.

Include the reporty-ng repository in your pom (see: https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/wiki/MavenPlugin)

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>reporty-ng</id>
        <url>https://github.com/cosminaru/reporty-ng/raw/master/dist/maven</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Also, in the previous URL i can see a space before 1.2.pom https://bitbucket.org/Devraj/reporty-ng/reporty-ng/1.2/reporty-ng- 1.2.pom