# How to use Stash as a Maven remote repository for a Gradle project?

Tags: maven, gradle, bitbucket-server

How can I reference a custom remote **Maven repository** which is hosted on [Stash (aka. Bitbucket Server)](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server)? Here is what I tried in the root `build.gradle`:

```groovy
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // This Stash path does not work
            url "https://stash.company.lan/projects/AP/repos/internal-repository"
        }
        maven {
            // This GitHub path works fine
            url "https://github.com/user/mvn-repo/tree/master"
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out the correct path to the *raw* folder structure for Stash so Gradle understands. When I reference a library stored in the repository the following error is thrown:

> Error:Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want use Stash, because using SCM instead [Nexus](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/index.html) is not so good way...
But, if you want, check `nebula plugin` for gradle, [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-stash-plugin) is it. Maybe it will help you ;)

Just

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen Mols describes a setup in his article:

- [Git as a secure private Maven repository](http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/) (05.02.2016)

I have not tried it yet since I decided to install a local *Nexus* instance meanwhile. Please comment here if it worked for you.